# Insert candidate with categories + BullHorn

Tags: php, api, rest, categories

I'm trying to save and update a candidate in Bullhorn through the REST API with PHP.
 
I've loaded a candidate from BullHorn and my categories are shown this way:

```
["categories"]=>
object(stdClass)#632 (2) {
  ["total"]=>
  int(2)
  ["data"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
["category"]=>
object(stdClass)#654 (1) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1123135)
}
```

I can see that my id is equal to `1123135`. But how can I know which categories these are? I've selected two categories in BullHorn and my id is now **1123135**... . I have categories like "*E-marketing Expert, Data Science, ...*".

But how can I update these categories based on the user's selected choices?

Answer (score 0):

Categories in Bullhorn are similar to most other entities. This is the way I do it

```
function BHGetCategoryData($entity_type, $entity_id) {

    $url = $_SESSION['restUrl'].'entity/'.$entity_type.'/'.$entity_id.'?BhRestToken='.$_SESSION['BhRestToken'].'&fields=id,name';

    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,    
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      
        ); 

    $ch  = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $data = curl_exec( $ch ); 

    $obj = json_decode($data, true);

    curl_close( $ch ); 

    return $obj;

}

function BHQueryCategory() {

    $url = $_SESSION["restUrl"]."/query/Category?where=enabled=true%20AND%20id>1&fields=id,name&orderBy=id&count=100&BhRestToken=".$_SESSION["BhRestToken"];


    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,    
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      
        ); 

    $ch  = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $data = curl_exec( $ch ); 

    $obj = json_decode($data, true);

    return $obj;


}

// This dumps a list of categories
var_dump(BHQueryCategory());

$entity_id= 1123135;
$entity_type='Category';

// This will query one category for the name and id
var_dump(BHGetCategoryData($entity_type, $entity_id));
```

This of course assumes that you have your rest url and rest token and all that stuff taken care of.

Because of time delays in dynamically pulling all your categories, I would probably suggest that you download the full list and populate it client side - rather than calling the query every-time you want to populate a dropdown.

Also here is a confusing bit. There is "Category" which can be written as a single value to a Candidate record. There is also "Categories" which is a "To-Many" relationship and cant be written with the main entity, it must be called separately. Below is a function that will do that.

```
function BHCreateCandidateToMany($candid,$codegroup,$codestring) {

$url = $_SESSION['restUrl'].'entity/Candidate/'.$candid.'/'.$codegroup.'/'.$codestring.'?BhRestToken='.$_SESSION['BhRestToken'];

echo $url;


$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => Array("Content-Type: application/json"),
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT", 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,    
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120, 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      
  ); 

$ch  = curl_init( $url ); 
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
$data = curl_exec( $ch ); 

$obj = json_decode($data, true);

curl_close( $ch ); 

return $obj;
}
```

The documentation is found here - http://developer.bullhorn.com/documentation/rest-api-1-1-update

(Please tidy up the code as needed - just a rough draft to get you on your way)

Comment: What should be the values of the $codegroup,$codestring variables?

Comment: $codegroup = 'specialties'; or $codegroup = 'categories'; or $codegroup = 'category'; Its difficult to say because each system is customised, also just to confuse us "A category that has a value for parentCategoryId greater than zero is a specialty." $codestring='1123135'; again this will be system specific