# How to add Companies in bullhorn using Rest Api?

Tags: php, api, rest

I am developing php application for submitting my Employers data into bullhorn using rest api.

I have bullhorn account and client id and client secret

I read documentation and also  see question in

[[Insert candidate with categories + BullHorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072074/insert-candidate-with-categories-bullhorn][1])

one of stack overflow but not find any solution

Can any one help me how to use api for php??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Below Code I used to Create an company in BullHorn CRM using RESTAPI

Here Use Company as ClientCorporation object.

```
 $url = 'https://rest2.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-services/rggmp/entity/ClientCorporation?BhRestToken=09c4822e-04e7-40d8-9570-addc5c447aa7';
 $params =array("name"=> "Maha","fax"=>231312313 );
 $post_params = json_encode($params);
 $curl = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,$method);   // for Create -> "PUT"  & Update ->"POST" //
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: '.strlen($post_params));  
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);                               
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 $result = curl_exec($curl);
 $response = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($response);
curl_close($curl);
```

Output :

(

```
[changedEntityType] => ClientCorporation
[changedEntityId] => 304
[changeType] => INSERT
```

)

Comment: can you explain about the process to create ClientContact ?

Comment: Instead of clientCorporation , use ClientContact.

ClientCorporation - field is required for creating clientcontact.
 $url = 'https://rest2.bullhornstaffing.com/rest-services/rggmp/entity/ClientContact?BhRestToken=09c4822e-04e7-40d8-9570-addc5c447aa7';
 $clientCorporation = array("id" => 299 ) ;
 $params =array("name"=> "Maha","clientCorporation" =>  $clientCorporation);

Comment: ok, thanks maha. And one more thing, how to point the candidate resume with the applications. Because currently candidate entity doesn't have the file or resume entity. Thanks in advance !